# What happens when you divide by zero with a binary divider?

Tags: digital-logic, binary

I am curious what would happen if you have a number such as 2 (10 in binary) and divide by 0 (0 in binary). What would happen?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest versions it would enter an infinite loop because you repeatedly subtract divisor from the dividend until the dividend until the dividend is zero and count how many subtractions took place. But if the divisor is zero then the dividend never reaches zero so it continues trying forever:

[Mechanical calculator dividing by zero](http://youtube.com/watch?v=OFJUYFlSYsM)

In better versions this is caught with a special case.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Interesting video too.